# Meshes in 3DS Max does not have same number of vertices

Tags: blender, mesh, 3dsmax, vertices, fbx

I have two meshes with same vertices number in 3DS Max, but when I export it, both have not the same vertices number.
- I have to create a "ProOptimizer" modifier, to get the same number of vertices in all meshes.
- I export it as ".Obj", and uncheck all parameters, except textures, to keep it.
- I import it from Blender and I export it as ".FBX".

If I export it directly from 3DS Max, the vertices number is very different between all meshes, I do not understand.

How do I get the same vertices?

Can anyone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried to convert the mesh from "Edit Poly" to "Edit Mesh", but it does not works.

Comment: The question is a bit vague, what do you need the meshes for, for morph targets? Because then you don't just need the same amount of vertices but also the right vertex order. ProOptimizer will definitely change vertex order, maybe suply a sample file with the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do both meshes have same smoothing groups applied to the same respective triangles? And are the UV mapping similar?

Both normals (smoothing groups), and UV coordinate distribution can affect how many times a single vertex need to be split in order to render correctly, or get exported to a specific format. For example one vertex can have many normals (one for each neighboring triangle, e.g. in a box), forcing the vertex to be counted several times. Or on the contrary a vertex can have a single normal, making all neighboring faces appearing "smoothed" around the vertex.